# Node.js catch request that caused uncaughtException/unhandledRejection?

Tags: node.js

In node app we are listening for unhandled exceptions/rejections in the app entry file:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection'
...
```

Requests come in like this(same process):

```
server.all('/req', async (req, res) => {
...
```

Problem? We have no way of knowing which request exactly caused the crash. Is there any way we could pass some `req` request info back to the exception handler, so we can later check logs and replay the problematic request?

Edit: We are using express and crashes are caused by external libraries not related to express.

Comment: Yes, we do. Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: According to [express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). The errors from requests are handled by express itself, unless you wanna write a custom error handling function. @Nema Ga

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to create a function wrapper to catch all the errors and send them to the error middleware:

```
const asyncErrorHandler = fn =>
  function errorHandler (req, res, next, ...args) {
    const fnReturn = fn(req, res, next, ...args)
    return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next) // Errors are sent to next()
  }
```

Then you have to wrap all your routes with the error handler:

```
app.get('/', asyncWrap(async function(req, res, next) {
  const data = await Database.get({id: 1) // Unhandled errors are automatically sent to next()
  if (someCondition) throw new Error(); // This error is automatically sent to next() too
  res.render('index');
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the request endpoint in the console, use,

```
server.all('/req', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    // Logic here
}
```